# Javascript detecting wether or not user has a mouse

Tags: javascript, mobile, mouse

This is not for design, I'm making a tutorial where I would either ask the user to tap or to click on things.

Right now I'm using:

```
("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement);
```

But this fails on laptops with a touchscreen.

Comment: See the [`pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer) media query feature.

Comment: @SebastianSimon how do I access it in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for that. To detect a mouse, your query would look like that:

```
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    // 'hover' means a device that supports hovering
    // 'pointer: fine' means an accurate pointing device, as opposed to limited pointing device like touchscreen (where you would use 'coarse' value
}
```

Note that this query will detect touch pad as well but it will not detect smartphones, touchscreens, stylus-based screens or other controllers like Nintendo Wii, Microsoft Kinect.

**To run the same query from JavaScript**, you can use [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
if (matchMedia('(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine)').matches) {
  // You code
}
```